# Problems with Dojo ShrinkSafe

Tags: javascript, dojo, shrink

I'm trying to minify a JavaScript file using the [online Dojo Shrinksafe service](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/), but it's giving me an empty file.

What's going on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ShrinkSafe is deprecated. Use the online [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) or [UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) instead if you need to minify code online.

Comment: Why is it deprecated?

Comment: It’s deprecated because it’s old and there are newer better solutions (as linked in the answer).